# Very large index on 2 billion unique rows

Tags: sql, indexing, database-indexes

I have a table that has over 2 billion rows. The clustered index on it consists of almost all of the fields due to the unique nature of the data. The data is also updated daily. The index is larger than the database (300GB vs almost 800GB) Is an index that size even worth the amount of space it is taking based on speed?

Comment: *WHAT* concrete database is this for? In SQL Server, the clustered index **IS** the data!

Comment: How fragmented is the index?  Updating columns in a clustered index is usually a bad practice - have you tried using a non-clustered index instead?

Comment: @marc_s I think the clustered index is a compound key that _consists_ of most of the columns, not _includes_.

Comment: @DStanley No, the clustered index is the table. It consists of the columns defined in the key, and includes all other columns of the table. That is the whole point of a clustered index, it is also why you can have only one.